# Argumentos python como un string

Tags: python, python-2.7, string, python-2.x

Estoy atascado en un script. Os intento exponer a ver si me podeis ayudar.

Defino lo siguiente antes de entrar en el loop.

> cliente, fecha, hora, state, nombre, result, most_repeated = sys.argv[1].split()
>
> timestamp = str(fecha)+' '+' '+str(hora)
>
> CLIENTE 08-01-2018 08:44:00 1 Prueba1 ALERT 4000 192.168.1.113 ==>> 8.8.8.8:53 ==>> DNS

La ejecución es la siguiente:

```
./script.py "CLIENTE 08-01-2018 08:44:00 1 nombre de la alerta que sea 5000 192.168.1.113 ==>> 8.8.8.8:53 ==>> DNS"
```

Al meter espacios entre los parametros esto los toma como diferentes parametros como todos sabemos.

Quiero que:

concretamente los campos

```
./script.py "CLIENTE 08-01-2018 08:44:00 1 nombre de la alerta que sea 5000 192.168.1.113 ==>> 8.8.8.8:53 ==>> DNS"
```

Lo tome como un unico parametro.

Lo he estado formateando con "%s" Pero cuando salgan mas palabras en el nombre de la alerta no funcionará.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto lo puedes resolver usando variables estrella `*var` de forma que guardas todas las demás entradas en una variable, para tu caso sería algo así.

```
import sys

cliente, fecha, hora, state, *otros= sys.argv[1].split()

print(cliente, fecha, hora, state, otros)

# CLIENTE 08-01-2018 08:44:00 1 ['nombre', 'de', 'la', 'alerta', 'que', 'sea', '5000', '192.168.1.113', '==>>', '8.8.8.8:53', '==>>', 'DNS']
```

Puedes ver que la variable `otros` es una lista con todas las demás entradas, si repetimos esta idea ahora desempaquetando esta variable podemos obtener los demás valores.

```
*nombre, result, ip1, _, ip2, _, most_repeated = otros

print(nombre, result, ip1, ip2, most_repeated)

# ['nombre', 'de', 'la', 'alerta', 'que', 'sea'] 5000 192.168.1.113 8.8.8.8:53 DNS
```

En este segundo paso usamos la variable estrella al comienzo, y definimos las últimas variables a tomar, haciendo esto ahora la variable nombre queda en una lista y los demás parámetros en variables independientes.

Y ya puedes sacar solo el nombre uniendo esta lista

```
nombre = ' '.join(nombre)
```